# How to select particular field in address book in iPhone

Tags: iphone

i am working on one app and in that i have to open the address book, i have used ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to open address book and in that have stored phone number and email for all the user, however i didnd't know how to store the value of phone number or email, suppose if user clicks on email field the email address stores in some variable and if clicks on phone number store in another variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Please find the code below......

You can get FirstName,LastName ,Image of the person and MobileNumber from your iPhone addressbook

Add Button to your ViewController and add this code to your button click event.

```
-(IBAction)btnGetNameClicked:(id)sender {
      // creating the picker
     ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
     // place the delegate of the picker to the controll
     picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

     // showing the picker
     [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    // releasing
    [picker release];
 }

 -(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

     // setting the first name
     lblFirstName.text = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

     // setting the last name
     lblLastName.text = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);   

    ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    lblNumber.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
    if(ABPersonHasImageData(person)){
         imgPerson.image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person)];
    } else {
         imgPerson.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NotAvailable.png"];
    }

    // remove the controller
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;
 }
```

Comment: thanks marvin however i am working on the given function - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
  while selecting name it is showing the name and email property from there selecting any one of the property should store the value